# Lenovo Touchpad issue 20.04

Tags: xorg, touchpad, 20.04, lenovo, synaptics

I decided to swap from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04 (I'm a newbie) and I found a problem with the touchpad.

`uname -r` gives: `5.4.0-33-generic`

`xinput` gives:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It shows the touchpad as *PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse*.

```
xserver-xorg is already the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu14).
```

What I've tried:

I installed first the binary:

```
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.9.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

No problems, but the touchpad still not working.

I'd appreciate help to fix this issue; I know that it is known issue, and probably the solution is in front of me, but you can appreciate I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: First of all there is no need to install any version of `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. It can only spoil the system and break dependencies. `libinput` is used as a user space driver in Ubuntu 20.04. I suggest removing that package. 2) If your touchpad is not shown in xinput it makes no sense at all trying to tinker with user space drivers. The problem is with the kernel support. Most likely this touchpad is not supported yet, or needs some kernel option to workaround it. The latter is unlikely.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a Logitech mouse attached? Please add the full output of `xinput` to your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to uninstall the synaptics package.
I was trying to follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection#Some_general_work_flow_for_Triagers;

Comment: Why do you think the touchpad is detected as a Logitech mouse? Are you using a mouse? It looks like the touchpad is not detected at all.

Comment: I used a mouse after 3 weeks of frustration as not using the touchpad in a laptop is quite annoying... did I mess it up by plugging in a mouse?

Comment: You didn't mess it, but the statement that your touchpad is detected as a mouse is wrong. The mouse is detected as a mouse.

Comment: I have uninstall the xorg package and now  the touchpad is recognised.

Thanks a lot; I restarted the laptop and now it is working!!

It doesn't have all the functions, but I can scroll again.

Answer (score 4):

For my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15IIL05  - i5-1035G1 [Michael Reutman's (mreutman) solution in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1880172/comments/53) worked like a charm. I had to:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` (with `nano /etc/default/grub`) and change the following line as shown:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="[...]"
   ```

   To

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs quiet splash"
   ```
2. Update GRUB:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I've removed `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`, unplugged the auxiliary mouse and restart the laptop.

The touchpad is recognised and the main functions working.

Thanks Pilot6 for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY way I can get my  trackpads to function properly on my Thinkpad t469 and t15 is to install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Comment: My laptop is a Lenovo ideapad Y700. I still need to restart the touchpad several times after login to have the scrolling function, but synaptic drivers were making the issue worst. It is a know bug and until it's resolved, we need to live with it! I'm thinking about installing Fusuma...

Comment: On my Lenovo T460s on Linux Mint, this seems to have fixed some weird trackpad behavior where the trackpad would "work" and then "freeze" and move down a couple pixels and be unresponsive for a few seconds. Seems to be better now!