# Touchpad Lenovo P14s 20.04 LTS stopped working

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

This week, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Lenovo P14s. Initially everything, including the touchpad, worked out of the box. Today though, my touchpad stopped working. Since in another forum the question was asked and the person trying to help asked for *xinput* and *xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"* (the person asking the question did not reply further), I thought to do the same here.

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3       id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3       id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]


$ xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (155):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (157): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (296): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (297): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (298):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (299):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (300):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (301):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (302):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (303):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (304):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (305):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (306):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (307):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (308):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (309):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (310):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (311): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (312):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (313):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (314):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (315):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (316): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (317): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (318): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (319): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (277): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (278):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (279):    0, 0
    Device Node (280):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (281):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (320):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (321):   1
```

PS: I wasn't able to understand what resolved the problem in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246978/lenovo-touchpad-issue-20-04). I tried turning off my MX Master 3, but it had no effect on the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

After some time the touchpad stop working. However, the buttons and the nob were still working. I found this issue when I've changed the configuration of the BIOS to have sticky Fn key. I've also swapped the Fn for the Ctrl. I was not very used to the new configuration, so I accidentally pressed Ctrl (Fn function) and +V. After that ( I was writing some code with vim) the v letter started to be printed all the way and the touchpad stopped working.

Restarting fixed the issue but I've tried to kill the process with `kill -9` command. Even though the command was processed, Ubuntu was not killing it.

After the restart, as I said, everything was working fine. However I found this log in `dmesg`

```
Apr 11 13:39:28 mgs-p14 kernel: [    1.979870] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: LEN2064 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
    Apr 11 13:39:28 mgs-p14 kernel: [    2.055943] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 10.32, id: 0x1e2a1, caps: 0xf014a3/0x940300/0x12e800/0x500000, board id: 3471, fw id: 2909640
    Apr 11 13:39:28 mgs-p14 kernel: [    2.055958] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
    Apr 11 13:39:28 mgs-p14 kernel: [    2.106618] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
    Apr 11 13:39:28 mgs-p14 kernel: [    2.141437] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
    Apr 11 13:39:28 mgs-p14 kernel: [    2.147929] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
    Apr 11 13:39:28 mgs-p14 kernel: [    2.151433] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
```

This is the the device recognized by ubuntu
─$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -A 20 Synaptic

```
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

Here I found some troubleshooting tutorial that might also help. I will follow it when I experience again the issue and let you know
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection